# Where is created Wifi hotspots located?

Tags: wireless, network-manager, hot-spot

I use my small homeserver as Wifi hotspot. Usually I just use the ad hoc "internet sharing" hotspot feature in NetworkManager.

Today I created a new Hotspot, without password, because I needed it for a few hours.

Now I want to remove it again, but even after removing it, its still running!

It is nowhere to found in NetworkManager, but my other devices still see it and can connect to it.

I have looked here:

```
/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/
```

And deleted all files in there (except my wired connection).

I also found a bunch of `*wlan0.lease` files in:

```
/var/lib/NetworkManager/
```

which I deleted.

I even rebooted the entire machine, but the hotspot still runs everytime I enable wifi.

Does anyone know where I can find the created Hotspot and delete/remove it?

Comment: same problem here. do you have some update on this thread?

Comment: I think I ended up purging and reinstalling networkmanager. But sadly I don't remember if that did the trick

Comment: Thanks. This is a very really annoying issue. I've asked a related question.  No answers until now.